# Ubuntu logs issues

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, log

I am accessing the Ubuntu logs via the

```
 cd /var/log 
 username@username-XPS-13-9310:/var/log$ tail -f syslog
```

I get

```
Jan 17 19:45:55 xbass-XPS-13-9310 NetworkManager[809]: <warn>                    
[1705495555.2180] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[7: 
fe80::df6d:7462:225:5854]: failure 13 (Permission denied)
Jan 17 19:45:56 xbass-XPS-13-9310 NetworkManager[809]: <warn> 
 [1705495556.2517] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2:
 fe80::7861:57e3:a37f:b69e]: failure 13 (Permission denied)
Jan 17 19:45:57 xbass-XPS-13-9310 NetworkManager[809]: <warn>  [1705495557.2194] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[7: fe80::9bb2:1e03:9349:cd61]: failure 13 (Permission denied)
Jan 17 19:45:58 xbass-XPS-13-9310 NetworkManager[809]: <warn>  [1705495558.2529] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::f33:e3be:9997:148a]: failure 13 (Permission denied)
Jan 17 19:45:59 xbass-XPS-13-9310 NetworkManager[809]: <warn>  [1705495559.2203] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[7: fe80::5785:9f45:a953:9d57]: failure 13 (Permission denied)
Jan 17 19:46:00 xbass-XPS-13-9310 NetworkManager[809]: <warn>  [1705495560.2534] ipv6ll[3325977be1a6d754,ifindex=2]: changed: no IPv6 link local address to retry after Duplicate Address Detection failures (back off)
Jan 17 19:46:01 xbass-XPS-13-9310 NetworkManager[809]: <warn>  [1705495561.2217] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[7: fe80::60dc:4589:16e8:3061]: failure 13 (Permission denied)
Jan 17 19:46:01 xbass-XPS-13-9310 cron[845]: (*system*) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/crontab)
Jan 17 19:46:01 xbass-XPS-13-9310 cron[845]: (*system*e2scrub_all) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/cron.d/e2scrub_all)
Jan 17 19:46:01 xbass-XPS-13-9310 cron[845]: (*system*anacron) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/cron.d/anacron)
```

Does anybody know what is going on? I fell upon these logs about Network Manager issue, by researching, since i get unstable wifi or i need to restart my laptop when i connect to a new Network etc, the wifi is not working smoothly, in general.
This is a Dell XPS 13 laptop on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

[image: Laptop specifications]

Comment: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Comment: ok that did the job. I can use this command whenever i have some network issues, cool.

Comment: @petep Just to say it is the right answer. Encouraging you to post an answer.

Comment: @xbass540 the last three lines in your syslog show that you have made files under `/etc` world writable. This means that anyone with access to your system can trivially get root permissions (or zap your disks: e.g. `echo "* * * * * root rm -rf /" >>/etc/crontab` will do the job in a minute). Of course, it's your personal laptop and not a multi-user system, but I'd still not leave such security holes open.

Comment: @zwets should i make them 644 or what?

Comment: The files mentioned in the syslog should be 644, but the fact that they are in multiple locations under `/etc` suggests that other files may be affected as well.

Comment: @petep after few days working with the laptop, unfortunately the restart of the Network Manager doesn't solve the issue. I restart and it stubbornly refuses to make the Ethernet connection work. I managed to connect to the wi-fi though after few restarts or totally turn off.